# Android messaging no longer works for me in Tor

Tags: security

I have used messages.android.com on Tor for a long time. Recently though after navigating to the website, a permission request popped up. Having never seen it before, I declined the permission. From then on, the site will no longer display the QR code necessary to sync the phones contacts. I looked everywhere on Tor for these permissions. The closest I found was under privacy under Tracking Protection and Cookies and Site Data but to no avail. So the question is how can I get Tor to prompt me again for that permission that was displayed?

Comment: I might also add that the QR code will display for a fraction of a second and then disappear. If that helps any.

Answer (score 1):

Never mind. I played with some of the settings and found that using "New identity" under the file tab allowed it to reset and when I navigated to messages.android.com this time, it offered the permission I had previously declined.